# Is "tranquilar(se)" still used to mean "tranquilizar(se)" in any Spanish dialects?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, sinónimos, palabras-raras, dialectos

English learners of Spanish sometimes say<sup>1</sup> "tranquílate" in place of the more usual "tranquilízate", presumably due to the influence of the adjective *tranquila/o* and/or the English cognate *tranquil* (as opposed to the false friend *tranquilize*).

I was under the impression that [*tranquilar(se)*](http://dle.rae.es/?w=tranquilar) was a long outdated word among native speakers in this context<sup>2</sup>, but it pops up a few times in [Google Ngrams](https://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_es&&tbm=bks&q=tranqu%C3%ADlese+OR+tranqu%C3%ADlate+OR+tranquilarse+OR+tranquilarte) in the past few decades. E.g.:

> **Tranquílese**, siéntese ¿Un café? [`Justo Vasco, 1992`](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=RkRJ77zp6ToC&pg=PA156&dq=tranqu%C3%ADlese)

> Siéntese usted y **tranquílese**, Guadalupe.  `Arturo Pérez-Reverte, 1993`

> **Tranquílese** directora, yo soy muy creyente y todo esto... [`Antonio Zurita, 2012`](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=KOrJ8Xc8pQoC&pg=SL3-PA129&dq=tranqu%C3%ADlese)

Assuming these aren't printing errors or [idiolectal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiolect) quirks:

**Is *tranquilar(se)* still used with the meaning of *tranquilizar(se)* in any Spanish dialects?**

---

1. <sup>e.g. «Bayani puts a hand on his shoulder. “Tranquílate, hermano. The men are all ready to march."» [`John Sayles, 2011`](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=zTr2BQAAQBAJ&pg=PT779&dq=tranqu%C3%ADlate)</sup>
2. <sup>e.g. here it is used to imitate an archaic style of speech:</sup>
   <sup>«Tranquílate, mi amigo, tened buena creencia, cerca están grandes gozos de la vuestra querencia.» `Héctor Azar, 1955`</sup>

Comment: Not in Colombia. It is the first time I hear "tranquílese" and sounds absolutely awful to me.

Comment: Reading the first paragraphs of the "porque yo?" book and given the kind of language used, I would not trust the quality of the Spanish used in that book. It would be like considering correct the language used on [La vendedora de rosas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_vendedora_de_rosas)

Answer (score 1):

**[Tranquilar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=aHymAej)** does exist in the [Spanish dictionary](http://www.rae.es/).

I'm a native Spanish speaker, from Spain, and never heard of that word. I guess it must be a very old word that no one uses nowadays.

Here, in Spain, we do use the word **tranquilizar(se)**, as well as **calmar(se)**.